# Only mic or speaker works on Google hangouts meet, both not working simultaneously

Tags: iphone, audio, sound-volume, call, video-conference

I am using Google Hangouts Meet on iphone 5. It was working well. Suddenly an issue happened. When I click on sound symbol on top of meet screen, two options pop out: iPhone and speaker. When I select iPhone as sound device, I can hear people, but my voice is inaudible to people. When I select speaker as sound device, people can hear me but I can't hear audience. So only one way communication in  either case. I checked volume, it is full. The regular phone call works  without any trouble.I already uninstalled and installed app. Try restart of iPhone, updating iOS but strange issue continues.

Comment: It's not clear - "regular phone call" is that a regular phone call using Google or a regular phone call using cellular?  Have you tried other apps to see if the problem is there as well?

Comment: Regular phone call works on speaker or normal mode. Which other apps do I need to test?  I think if mic and speaker works in regular phone calls, it is not hardware issue. Either there might be some settings in Meet (which I can't find) or bug in Meet app.

Comment: Regular phone calls are cellular calls.